# check null values in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a question on null values. The following is the tricky one for me. Can anyone suggest to me how can we check if the value is null?

```
locals {
  application_vars = {
    "oke_build" = [
      "121",
      "121",
      "121",
    ]
    "ipa" = [
      "101.10.2,1",
      "101.10.2,2",
      null
    ]
    "size" = [
      "c4.8xlarge",
      null,
      null,
    ]
  }
```

}

I want to verify if the list contains null values.

Comment: Your question is not clear. None of your variables, a,b,c, is null. Do you have an actual example of what you want to do with a null value?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. I updated the question @Marcin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [compact](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/compact) function to return only non-null elements from a list.

Then, you could compare the length of the original list with the length of the list returned by the `compact` function.

```
locals {
  application_vars = {
    "oke_build" = [
      "121",
      "121",
      "121",
    ]
    "ipa" = [
      "101.10.2,1",
      "101.10.2,2",
      null
    ]
    "size" = [
      "c4.8xlarge",
      null,
      null,
    ]
  }
}

output "not_null_check_oke_build" {
  value = length(compact(local.application_vars.oke_build)) == length(local.application_vars.oke_build) ? "has no null elements" : "has null elements"
}

output "not_null_check_ipa" {
      value = length(compact(local.application_vars.ipa)) == length(local.application_vars.ipa) ? "has no null elements" : "has null elements"
    }

output "not_null_check_size" {
      value = length(compact(local.application_vars.size)) == length(local.application_vars.size) ? "has no null elements" : "has null elements"
    }
```

> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
>
> Outputs:
>
> not_null_check_ipa = "has null elements"
>
> not_null_check_oke_build = "has no null elements"
>
> not_null_check_size = "has null elements"

If you have too many lists to check, this would get repetitive & you gotta loop these with another for a loop. But for 2-3 lists, it's okay to have them this way.